Which Latin verb can I wrap gifts with?
It is common today to wrap gifts given at Christmas or a birthday.
I'm not aware of the Romans doing so, but they must have wrapped something in a comparable manner.
Which (preferably but not necessarily classical) Latin verb would be the best translation of "to wrap" in the context of Christmas gifts?
The options that come to mind are volvere and tegere, possibly with a prefix like in-, but I imagine there are also relevant verbs that I didn't cross my mind.

What about the verb "involvo"?

@AntônioSilva That was among my own suggestions (volvere & -in), and it might well be the best choice. If it is indeed a good one, it should be written into an answer.

The verb "amicio" is a good choice. There's a sentence on L&S. Check it.

@AntônioSilva Involvo and amicio are both fine choices and will do the job, but I prefer obvolvo and its near-synonym obtego, because they carry more of sense of concealment, which is basically what wrapping presents is all about.
